# Fundamental group of a certain space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider a space $X$ constructed by removing a disk $D$ from the torus $T$ and gluing a 2-cell via an attaching map to the boundary of this disk of degree 2. What is the fundamental group of the space $X$?

I've thought about van-Kampen's theorem but get a little confused right at the start. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $T \setminus D$ in $X$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of the attached 2-cell in $X$. This seems like the "usual" decomposition for van-Kampen's theorem (i.e. make $U, V$ each one of the separate "pieces").

However, I don't know what do to figure out what $U, V$, and $U \cap V$ are homotopy equivalent to. For instance, for $U \cap V$, if I retract "from the attached 2-cell" side, then it looks like I get two copies of the circle, since it's attached with a degree 2 map; but if I retract "from the torus" side, then it looks like I just get one circle.

Similarly, because the attaching map is not the identity, I don't know how $U$ and $V$ retract to a well-known space. If we let $c$ be the boundary disk of the attached 2-cell, I believe the attaching map sends $c \mapsto c^2$ i.e. the boundary of the disk cut out on the torus should be $c^2$ (not just $c$), and I am confused how to continue. Perhaps I should consider a different partition for van-Kampen? Is there a way to make it work with the $U, V$ I chose?

**Edit after reading comments, with an attempted solution:** Letting $U, V$ be as above, we have the homotopy equivalences mentioned in the comments (so $\pi_1(U \cap V) \mathbb{Z}, \pi_1(U) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}, \pi_1(V) = 0$). Therefore $\pi_1(X)$ is $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/ N$ for some almalgamation subgroup $N$. This is found by the inclusion of the generating loop of $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ into $\pi_1(U)$ (since $\pi_1(V)$ is trivial). Since the $U \cap V$ is a circle, which can be deformed to the boundary of the attached 2-cell which is then wrapped twice around the cut-out disk in the torus, and then this is homotopy equivalent to tracing out the boundary of the torus (i.e. in the standard unit-square representation), which is $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2 = [a, b]^2$. Thus,
$$
\pi_1(X) = \langle a, b | [a, b]^2 \rangle.
$$

Comment: $U$ is torus minus a disk, unioned with a little bit of the cell, so it deformation retracts to $T \setminus D$ which is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of two circles. On the other hand, $V$ is the attached disk plus a little bit of the torus, so it is contractible. $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to the circle along which you're attaching.

Comment: @kamills So there's no issue about moving the boundary of $V$ through the attached boundary $c$ and having it wrap twice around?

Comment: Think about it this way: $V$ certainly deformation retracts to the attached 2-cell. Even though its boundary is wrapped twice around, the map $S^1 \xrightarrow{2} S^1 \to D^2$ is still nullhomotopic.

Comment: there's no issue. To account for the "twice around" you need to basically just analyze $\pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U)$.

Comment: Thanks for both the comments - I think that makes sense. So would the resulting group be $\langle a, b | [a, b]^2\rangle$? (I'll edit in details in my original post.)